# Trying to fit in Caret with this nav menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

https://jsfiddle.net/alachgar/L0bxjncz/3/

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

```
                <a href="#mobileMenu" id="mobileBar" class="d-none ml-auto"> <i class=" "></i></a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto justify-content-end" id="nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dd">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Justice Server <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dd">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Westlaw <span class="sr-only"> </span></a>
                            
                        </li>
                        
                        <li>
                            
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"  href = "#">LSNC SPN <span class = "caret sr-only"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <?php
                                $conn = new mysqli('localhost', '.....', '.......', 'portal') or die("Database Connection Failed");
                                            
                                //Below We are connectin to Database and getting all items for our Menu.
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
                                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
                                        {
                                            echo "<li class='dropdown-item'><a href='$base_url/admin/downloads.php?idx={$row['cat_code']}'><span >{$row['cat_name']}<span></a></li>";
                                        }   
                                ?>
                            </ul>                                   
                            
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item dd">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> LSNC Sites <span class="sr-only"> </span></a>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled dropdownMenu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"> LSNC Web</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"> Calfresh</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"> Regulations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"> Cases</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dd">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Pika <span class="sr-only"></span></a>                    
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dd">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Your JS Cases <span class="sr-only"></span></a>                    
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dd">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events <span class="sr-only"></span></a>                   
                        </li>   
                        <li class="nav-item dd">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>
```

I an trying to fit in a dropdown menu with this navbar, all items are good except when I query items from my MySql table, results shift to far left, I want items to display underneath the Main dropdown menu (LSNC SPN).
I tried all kind of combinations no luck.
Every help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code and it seems to me you have done everything right except you didn't add "nav-item" class to the "dropdown-menu"'s parent "li" tag.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right, now it is coming down perfectly except it needs some css, in other words it is not picking up my main css formatting.. any idea why ?

Comment: Update: 
Now when I add <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled dropdownMenu">, I get CSS. not perftct but perfect enough.

Comment: /* below is my final working Markup  */
       
       <li class="nav-item dd">
        
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle = "dropdown"  href = "#">LSNC SPN <span class = "sr-only"></span></a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled dropdownMenu">
         <?php
         ......          } 
         ?>
        </ul>         
        
       </li>